# Laravel (Post, Delete, Put) routes in Swagger

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, swagger, laravel-5.4

I have update the code for get method as follows which working properly
in swagger.

Can any one please suggest me the swagger code for post, put, delete with its laravel route, controller code. (As I mention follows for GET)

route/web.php

```
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/'], function () {
           Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
        });
```

DashboardController.php

```
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 *
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     path="/api/dashboard",
 *     description="Returns dashboard overview.",
 *     operationId="api.dashboard.index",
 *     produces={"application/json"},
 *     tags={"dashboard"},
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="Dashboard overview."
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response=401,
 *         description="Unauthorized action.",
 *     )
 * )
 */

public function index(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'result'    => [
            'statistics' => [
                'users' => [
                    'name'  => 'Name',
                    'email' => 'user@example.com'
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'message'   => '',
        'type'      => 'success',
        'status'    => 0
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Bellow laravel routes for swagger Post/Put/Delete.**

```
Route::post('/api/user', 'DashboardController@store');
Route::put('/api/user/{user_id}', 'DashboardController@edit');
Route::delete('/api/user/{user_id}', 'DashboardController@delete');
Route::get('/api/users', 'DashboardController@getData');
Route::get('/api/user/{user_id}', 'DashboardController@getDataById');
```

**For Post**

```
   /**
     * @SWG\Post(
     *      path="/api/user",
     *      tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1saveUser",
     *      summary="Add User",
     *      consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
     *      produces={"application/json"},
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="name",
     *          in="formData",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="string" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="phone",
     *          in="formData",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="number" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Success"
     *      ),
     */
```

**For Put**

```
   /**
     * @SWG\Put(
     *      path="/api/user/{user_id}",
     *      tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1UpdateUser",
     *      summary="Update User",
     *      consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
     *      produces={"application/json"},
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="user_id",
     *          in="path",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="string" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="name",
     *          in="formData",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="string" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Success"
     *      ),
     */
```

**For Delete By ID**

```
   /**
     * @SWG\Delete(
     *      path="/api/users",
     *      tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1DeleteUser",
     *      summary="Delete User",
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="user_id",
     *          in="path",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="string" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Success"
     *      ),
     */
```

**For Get**

```
    /**
     * @SWG\Get(
     *      path="/api/users",
     *      tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1GetUsers"
     *      summary="Get Users",
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Success"
     *      ),
     */
```

**For Get By ID**

```
    /**
     * @SWG\Get(
     *      path="/api/user/{user_id}",
     *      tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1GetUserById",
     *      summary="Get User by user id",
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="user_id",
     *          in="path",
     *          required=true, 
     *          type="string" 
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Success"
     *      ),
     */
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this

Comment: Okay, if you have any confusion you can tell me. Thanks

Comment: Ya sure, I will

Comment: this is really great. Thanks for the compact answer. But I have one question. what is consume doing in that case? and what should be the consume in case of the get method?

Answer (score 0):

I have found code parameters for post, delete routes at following link

```
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/Examples
```